# Few method calls in one hibernate transaction

Tags: java, hibernate, transactions

I have one @Transactional method A and few additional methods B and C which called from method A.

When I call methods B and C are they executed in transaction or not?
It looks like hibernate commit methods B and C immediately.

How can I commit B and C in one transaction with method A?

Comment: `It looks like hibernate commit methods B and C immediately.` What evidence do you have of this? Are `B` and/or `C` also annotated with `@Transactional`?

Comment: Hibernate throws exception which will be never thrown in one transaction.
B and C are not @Transactional now. But I tried with annotation and it is didn't help.

Comment: You can post valid code demonstrating your issue :), are you using spring with hibernate?

Comment: And post the stack trace of the exceptions.